# Import a matlotlibrc file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Simple question - I have a `.matplotlibrc` file with some defaults (e.g. http://home.strw.leidenuniv.nl/~turnerm/python.html) that I want to import/apply optionally with a simple switch in the code. How do I do this?

I could translate the `.matplotlibrc` syntax to regular python code, but I can't quite get this to work. Would `execfile()` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a new enough (as is off of master) version of mpl you can use the `style` module to update your current `rcparams`.  If you are using 1.3.x use [`rc_param_from_file`](http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc_params_from_file), but be aware it fill in any values you don't explicitly set with the default values.

This is an area where there is some active development to improve things.  If you could send a brief description of your use-case to the mpl-dev list that would be great :).

Comment: Sure - thanks - I'll try that and report back. What is the mpl-dev address?